# How to Deploy Fields with their visibilities with change sets?

Tags: deployment, profile, permissions, change-set

I've a requirement to deploy the below fields using ChangeSets from Sandbox to Production,

I have one field `CaseMode__c` visible to all profiles except two profiles and another custom field, `OffsetHour__c` that should be hidden for all profiles. These fields are available on Case Object.

Can I deploy these permissions with change sets or do I need to do this manually in production?

Answer (score 3):

Since its a custom field include the fields as well as profiles also in the changeset to configure permissions .I would recommend all profiles along with this field in one changeset for deployment with permission same as the source org .

Comment: This is the key point - if you want to deploy a FLS rule on a permission set, you have to include the field it is referencing as well - even if you aren't pushing any changes to that field...

Comment: @Mohith, how do you add profiles to a change set? There's a long list of things you can add (from `Action` to `Zone`), but there is no `Profile` in the list?

Comment: @JannieT That is done lower down on the edit page of the change set , in the section which currently is titled "Profile Settings For Included Components", by clicking the Add Profiles button. It leads to a page where you likely would select all the profiles.

Answer (score 0):

If you add profile permissions to a change set, they'll carry over the permissions they have in the sandbox for all and only the objects in the change set. So if you're change set has just two fields plus all profiles, and you've set up the permissions already, it'll deploy the way you want.

That said, IMHO, change sets are a royal pain in this department. If I were in your shoes, I'd deploy the two fields as a change set, which by default makes them invisible to all profiles. Then go to `CaseMode__c` and use the set field level security button to make it visible to the desired profiles ...

Comment: When you say to deploy the two fields as a change set -> If you are referring to Salesforce Change Sets then deploying the fields without profile will make the fields visible to no-one once deployed. The FLS settings are unchecked when deployed without profiles which makes it a royal PITA. Unless you know of a trick....

Answer (score 0):

@Ralph : Make sure you have your requirements of having **CaseMode__c** visible to all profiles except two and another field **OffsetHour__c** that should be hidden for all profiles completed in your source ORG.

Now while creating a changeset add all the profiles and the two custom fields in the changeset. This will ensure that all the visibility/permissions related to the two fields will moved to the destination ORG.